Wait time for interview process
I was one of the final three candidates for a tenure track position. How long does it usually take for the final decision to be reached and an offer sent out?  It has been about two weeks since my interview and I was the final candidate brought on to campus

Usually, the committee makes a decision quickly after the interviews are completed. Moreover, towards the end of the interview the committee usually informs the candidates about the next steps, i.e. on which time scale they will hear from them etc.
In your case, I presume that an offer was made to another candidate, who has not yet accepted. The fact that you haven't heard implies that you're still in the running should the favorite not accept the offer.
It may well be that an offer is followed by lengthy negotiations regarding the conditions and salary. In this case it would be only fair if the committee informs any second-choice candidates. In any case, it does not harm to just send them an email and ask for clarification.

Although two weeks to go from search committee to department chair to dean to HR might be pushing it. They might not have gotten an offer out yet.
